# Is there something similar to rails console in the PHP symfony framework?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, symfony

In rails, you can do `rails c` on the project root folder and it will pull up a REPL console with all the database models and methods loaded so you can do things easily in it so I was wondering whether there is something similar in the PHP Symfony framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel (using the symfony console) has something called laravel tinker. It's an interactive REPL console like you describe. I personally haven't heard of anything like this for symfony itself. But a quick google came up with this bundle: https://packagist.org/packages/theofidry/psysh-bundle

Or you can narrow down your searches on packagist: https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/tinker?query=REPL&type=symfony-bundle